# Azure Table Storage Listener for Enterprise Library Logging 5

Tags: azure, enterprise-library

Logging into azure storage would be economical that logging into SQL database.
Is there Windows Azure table storage listener available for Enterprise Library 5.

Comment: Is Enterprise Library 6 an option for you? It has Semantic Logging Application Block (SLAB) which writes to table storage.

Comment: @GauravMantri, Hey Gaurav, as the application is pretty big, it would be painful to update all references.

Comment: @GauravMantri, If it is not possible to find Azure table listener, I would rather create a custom exception handler. Don't see much benefit in upgrading the EntLib.